# How to remove simple product form cart in magento 2.1

Tags: php, magento2

I need to **remove** **simple product** from cart.

Remove item option available only for **configurable product**

```
<a href="#"
   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')); ?>"
   class="action action-delete btn-remove btn-remove2 remove-btn"
   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDeletePostJson(); ?>'>
   <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php /* <span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified * / echo __('Remove item')?>
    </span> */ ?>
</a>
```

Above code is working for **configurable product**

1. How to remove simple product from cart?

Comment: will this work?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141314/remove-items-from-cart-in-controller-magento2

Answer (score 0):

To delete items from cart you need to follow these functions:

```
public function deleteQuoteItems(){
    $checkoutSession = $this->getCheckoutSession();
    $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();//returns all teh items in session
    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    $itemId = $item->getItemId();//item id of particular item
    $quoteItem=$this->getItemModel()->load($itemId);//load particular item which you want to delete by his item id
    $quoteItem->delete();//deletes the item
    }
    }
    public function getCheckoutSession(){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager 
    $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');//checkout session
    return $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function getItemModel(){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager
    $itemModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');//Quote item model to load quote item
    return $itemModel;
    }
```

Comment: Where to add these functions?